# Most view product collection with Filter Magento 2.3.3

Tags: product-collection, mostview-product-collection

**Here, `product_type` is my custom product attribute.**

> This is custom script for getting most view product collection and
>   working well

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$mostViewedCollectionFactory = $obj->get('\Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$viewed = $obj->get('\Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed');


$productType = "925";
$collection = $mostViewedCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addViewsCount()
    ->setPageSize(10)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('product_type', array('eq' => $productType))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('neq' => '1'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left');


foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $productData = $product->getData();
}
```

> But not working on block file :-

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductList;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Class Related
 * @package Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductList
 */
class Related extends Template
{
    protected $mostViewCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $mostViewCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->mostViewCollectionFactory = $mostViewCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getRelatedProduct()
    {
        $current_product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');

        $productTypeId = $current_product->getProductType();

        $mostView = $this->mostViewCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addViewsCount()
            ->setPageSize(10)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('product_type', array('eq' => $productTypeId))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('neq' => '1'))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left');

        $alsoview_product_collection = [];
        foreach ($mostView as $item) {
            $product_id = $item->getEntityId();
            $product = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->load($product_id);
            $alsoview_product_collection[] = $product;
        }
        return $alsoview_product_collection;
    }

}
```

**I don't know why this not working in my module and working well on script**

Comment: Did you tried to echo  $productTypeId in your block ?

Comment: yes i got producttypeid